# Массив. Упорядочить значения

Tags: pascal

Дан массив X[6]. Нужно расположить в массиве Y[6] все значения из X[6] в определенном порядке, а именно сначала положительные, а затем отрицательные. Знаком с QBasic. Но нужно на паскале и получилось что-то такое. Ах да, в условии не упоминаются нули, поэтому не знаю, нужна ли вообще эта часть кода. Код писался под рандомные значения в этом массиве. 
В условии массив X[6]: [-3;2;8;-4;5;-1]. А получиться должен Y[6]: [2;8;5;-3;-4;-1]

> ### Pascal
>
> ```
> uses crt;
> var y,x:array[1..6] of integer;
> i,k:byte;
> begin
> clrscr; randomize;
> writeln('Mассив X(6):');
> for i:=1 to 6 do
> begin
>      x[i]:=random(199)-99;
>      write(x[i]:4);
>   end;
> k:=1;
> for i:=1 to 6 do
>   if x[i]>=0 then
>      begin
>         y[k]:=x[i];
>         inc(k);
>      end;
> writeln(#13#10,'Mассив Y(6):');
> for i:=1 to 6 do
>   begin
>      if x[i]<0 then
>         begin
>            y[k]:=x[i];
>            inc(k);
>         end;
>      write(y[i]:4);
>   end;
> readkey;
> end.
> ```

Вопрос в том, нет ли тут ошибок.

Comment: *В условии массив X[6]: [-3;2;8;-4;5;-1]. А получиться должен Y[6]: [2;8;5;-3;-4;-1]* Именно такой или с точностью до порядка элементов в подмассивах? Если второе - то код должен работать правильно.

Comment: Правильный код. Но можно избавиться от второго цикла и сделать все за один проход с дополнительной переменной. Положительные элементы будете заполнять с начала массива, а отрицательные с конца и декриментить вторую переменную.

Comment: @TO220 А всё равно будет второй цикл - для вывода массива :)

Comment: @Akina, в условии указано, что просто вывести сначала положительные, затем отрицательные. Как должен выглядеть код, что бы массив Y выглядел, как указано выше, то есть без учета порядка элементов в подмассивах.

Comment: @dAnTe48rus Этот код сейчас и будет отрабатывать согласно вашим условиям.